# Backup script on crontab not working

Tags: bash, ubuntu, backup, cron, tar

I have an script to backup my cvs, that simply tar the CVS directory, that's the script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash

CVS_ROOT="/home/cvs/data"

echo "=======================================" >> cvs_backup.log
echo "            CVS BACKUP START           " >> cvs_backup.log
echo "=======================================" >> cvs_backup.log
date >> cvs_backup.log
tar -czf cvs_backup.tar.gz $CVS_ROOT
echo "=======================================" >> cvs_backup.log
echo $(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') "End Backup" >> cvs_backup.log
echo "=======================================" >> cvs_backup.log
```

If I execute the script with ./backupScript.sh it works and generate my .tar.gz file, as well if I do /home/cvs/backups/backupScript.sh, but when I make that task automated with crontab (root, script has executing permissions to everyone too), it's not working. My crontab looks like this:

```
0 5 * * 1-5  /home/cvs/backup/cvs_backupScript.sh
```

I tried this too:

```
15 16 * * 1-5  /home/cvs/backup/cvs_backupScript.sh 2>/home/cvs/backup/errorBackup.log >/home/cvs/backup/output.log
```

Output files are generated, but nothing inside them.

thanks for all.

Comment: Are you sure are you calling the right script? I see two names here: **cvs_backup_temp.sh** and **backupScript.sh**.

Comment: yes, I'm sure, backupScript is just a name that I used to write here in SO, thanks for advise, I'll correct it now.

Comment: 1) check the PATH (it's different for cron scripts) 2) you can set up logging for cron scripts.

Comment: ok! I made a test: Created a dummy script that simply echo a dummytest on a dummy.txt, I've made a setup on crontab to execute it and it didn't worked too. so, how I can solthe the PATH problem you mean?

Comment: A script that just uses `echo` to a temp file should absolutely work. Check that script again. Where are you expecting that output cvs tarball to be because this script doesn't set a location it just uses wherever the script is run from (which, for cron, isn't a good default).

Comment: solved! just changed everything to absolute paths! thanks for this! I'm just a newbie and didn't even think about this, not even my teacher! :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change all paths to absolute path instead of relative path and all is solved.